# I need help querying LDAP with php

Tags: php, ldap

********Please read question in full......I am trying to figure out how to get an LDAP query to work...I am not asking why I am getting an Undefined Variable error, I am just stating that this is the only error I am getting when running the code.  I understand that the variable needs to be defined, even with the variable defined, no results are returned.

I'm trying to search LDAP with php. I don't need to add or edit information, just pull search results.  I've been reading the php manual entries and what examples I can, but am still having a little trouble.  With the code I have below, the only error I am getting is

> "Notice: Undefined variable: ad_users in ldapSearch() (line 42 of
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\TLSConnect3App\sites\all\modules\custom\TLSConnectPackage\ldap_search\includes\functions.php)."

I'm also trying to find out where to find samaccountname in LDAP.  Is that the uid or displayName?  My end goal is to be able to search a first/last name or email and pull the users photo, name, roll, and email.

```
<?php
function ldapSearch(){
    $ldap_password = 'H******5!!1';
    $ldap_username = 'cn=Directory Manager';
    $ldaphost = "ldap-server";
    $ldapport = 389;

    $ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost,$ldapport)
        or die('Could not connect to '.$ldaphost);

    // We have to set this option for the version of Active Directory we are using.
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); // We need this for doing an LDAP search.

    if (TRUE === ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldap_username, $ldap_password)){
        $ldap_base_dn = 'DC=,DC=co,DC=uk';
        $search_filter = '(&(objectCategory=person)(displayName= Admin))';
        $attributes = array();
        $attributes[] = 'givenName';
        $attributes[] = 'mail';
        $attributes[] = 'samaccountname';
        $attributes[] = 'sn';
        $result = ldap_search($ldapconn, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter, $attributes);
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
        if (FALSE !== $result){
            $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
            for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++){
                if (!empty($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]) &&
                    !empty($entries[$x]['mail'][0]) &&
                    !empty($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]) &&
                    !empty($entries[$x]['sn'][0]) &&
                    'Shop' !== $entries[$x]['sn'][0] &&
                    'Account' !== $entries[$x]['sn'][0]){
                        $ad_users[strtoupper(trim($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]))] = array(
                            'email' => strtolower(trim($entries[$x]['mail'][0])),
                            'first_name' => trim($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]),
                            'last_name' => trim($entries[$x]['sn'][0]));
                    }
            }
        }
        ldap_unbind($ldapconn); // Clean up after ourselves.
    }

$message = "Retrieved ". count($ad_users) ." Active Directory users\n";
}
```

Comment: Where is line 42? And what do you not understand about "Undefined variable"? Its meaning is quite clear.

Comment: I understand what the meaning is. I'm not asking what it means, i'm asking why it's happening. In other words, is there an error in the code? There is a reason why    $ad_users[strtoupper(trim($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]))] = array(
       'email' => strtolower(trim($entries[$x]['mail'][0])),
       'first_name' => trim($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]),
       'last_name' => trim($entries[$x]['sn'][0])); is not defining it.....if you look at the question you will see it's in regards to LDAP not my error. I just explained that this is the only error I am receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `$ad_users = array()` at the beginning of your function.

Comment: I did this, it didn't help.  When I print the $entries array, the count is 0 so it does't look like the query is pulling info at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$ad_users` is defined inside an `if` block, and then used outside it. If that `if` block is skipped then the variable will not be defined, and you will get a notice.

```
$something = false;

if ($something == true) { // This will be skipped
    $myVar = 'It works!'; // And this variable will not be defined
}
echo $myVar; // Notice: Undefined variable: myVar
```

In short, you need to make sure that `$ad_users` is defined, if you are going to use it. The easiest way would be to simply define the variable at the top of the function; that way it will always be available inside the entire function.